IIS Logs taking a long time to display request entries
Is there a way to make IIS dump requests to its log files as fast as possible?
Context
I'm facing a very long delay between a request I make to IIS being served and being actually logged to the IIS logs. That can range between 20s and 60s delay.
Some key points:

Once the request shows up in the log file, it shows the actual time the request happened,
the request reports being handled as fast as 350ms,
in IIS request logs the requests are not "stuck" either
the request is fully handled to the browser quickly
I could notice that in a production, lightly busy or not at all, Windows Server 2012 (IIS 6.2 build 9200)
same behavior in my development host, not busy at all, Windows 10 (IIS 10.0.19041.1)
production is in amazon storage (I can't tell the exact technology they use, it's derived from SSD I believe)
local storage is a SSD disk
if I monitor files in the same disk/filesystem updates to the files instantly reflect to the display (at most, if ever, 1s delay)

Some things I tried
I have tried tail -f or keep repeating tail command, and also Notepad++ with the "View > Monitoring (tail -f)" mode. All updating the file content at the same time, obeying the somewhat random, yet always long, delay.
From a copy of this question I posted (off-topic) in StackOverflow, Xudong Peng suggested I tried a flushByEntryCountW3CLog setting from IIS server-wide config file (%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config or IIS Manager top-level node (computer) > Configuration Editor > sites.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile). It did kind of make the logging interval change, but for worse. Felt now it was being dumped every minute, so I reverted it to 0.
On the topic above, I also ensured the specific <site> I was testing against didn't override the sitesDefault/logFile/flushByEntryCountW3CLog in applicationHost.config. Also recycled the application pool (so the sites were also recycled) and the setting sure would take effect. Still the same "behavior" change that seemed worse.
It seems that, even if the buffer (of that settings, 64k) is not filled, it gets dumped around every minute. Setting to 1 it felt the dump happened between 1 and 2 minutes.
I couldn't find any other setting regarding "logfile buffer" (so IIS would fill a buffer of log entries before "dumping" them to files).
Bottomline
Is this normal? Everybody dealing with IIS logs needs to take their time to check requests in the logs, or maybe there's a way to (at least temporarily) make IIS dump requests to the log file as quickly as possible?

The currently accepted answer from Greg Askew (thanks!) is not really what I am looking for but it sure does help, so until somebody finds an alternative that actually adjusts this flush interval (not automating the call of netsh of course), I think it's fair to keep it as the accepted one.

Have you tried:
netsh http flush logbuffer
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/forcing-iis-to-write-logs-http-and-ftp/ba-p/287872

You nailed it!.. It's kind of "a bummer" that I need to keep repeating the command when I want to see the log at once. Maybe there's a way to set up this logbuffer for a "more often" auto-flush?

@Avenger: You could create a scheduled task that runs the command and waits one second or some other interval...

That's what I plan to do for the time being. Actually just wrap a quick "for" loop in a command prompt as I don't really need this for a long time. Still hope something is buried in configs that might actually turn that flush "immediate".
